# Как вставить дочерний элемент, который я создаю с помощью обратных кавычек?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Я изобретаю велосипед и делаю свою корзину. Для добавления в корзину товара написал это:

```
let popularCars = document.querySelectorAll('.popularCarSlide '); //это карточка товара, который показывается в каталоге
let cartList = []

function addCartItem (title, price, img){ // это функция, которая создаёт элемент DOM
    let cartItem = `
    <div class="popupCartItem">
      <img src="`+ img + `" alt="" class="popupCarItemtImg">
      <p class="popupCartItemName">` + title + ` </p>
      <div class="popupCartPrice">
        <p class="popupCartPriceNum">` + price + `</p>
        <p class="popupCartPriceCredit">в кредит</p>
      </div>
      <svg class="popupCartItemDelete" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M2.21311 1.57107L16.3552 15.7132M2.21311 15.7132L16.3552 1.57107" stroke="#404040" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-linecap="square" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    `
    return (cartItem)
}

if(popularCars.length > 0) {
    let cartWraper = document.querySelector('.popupCartWraper')
    for(let i = 0; popularCars.length > i ; i++) {
        let carBtn = popularCars[i].querySelector('.popularSlideOstavitZayavku'),
            carTitle = popularCars[i].querySelector('.popularSlideName').textContent,
            carPrice = popularCars[i].querySelector('.popularSlideItemPriceText').textContent,
            carImg = popularCars[i].querySelector('.popularSlideImg').getAttribute('src');

        carBtn.onclick = ()=>{
            cartList.push ({ 
                            title: carTitle,
                            price: carPrice, 
                            img: carImg
                        })
            for(let o = 0; cartList.length > o; o++) {
                cartWraper.insertBefore(addCartItem(cartList[o].title, cartList[o].price, cartList[o].img), cartWraper.childNodes[o]) //попытка вставить элемент как дочерний
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но сталкиваюсь с ошибкой, что это не node элемент "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."
есть ли способ сделать из подобного элемента node и/или пихнуть его как дочерний элемент в контейнер?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

У которого есть 4-ре позиции для вставки:

```
'beforebegin': до самого element (до открывающего тега).
'afterbegin': сразу после открывающего тега element (перед первым потомком).
'beforeend': сразу перед закрывающим тегом element (после последнего потомка).
'afterend': после element (после закрывающего тега).
```

Соответственно применять этот метод надо будет уже к `cartWraper.childNodes[o]`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете немного модифицировать код функции, что бы он возвращал нужный вам тип данных, а именно Node

Создаете элемент div с помощью **document.createElement()**, в него добавляете оставшиеся элементы с помощью innerHTML и возвращаете уже элемент с типом HTMLDivElement(DOM Node)

```
function addCartItem(title, price, img) { 
    const cartItem = document.createElement('div');
    cartItem.classList.add('popupCartItem');
    cartItem.innerHTML = `<img src="${img}" alt="" class="popupCarItemtImg">
      <p class="popupCartItemName">${title}</p>
      <div class="popupCartPrice">
        <p class="popupCartPriceNum">${price}</p>
        <p class="popupCartPriceCredit">в кредит</p>
      </div>
      <svg class="popupCartItemDelete" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M2.21311 1.57107L16.3552 15.7132M2.21311 15.7132L16.3552 1.57107" stroke="#404040" stroke-width="2"
          stroke-linecap="square" />
      </svg>`;
    return cartItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, чтобы вставить HTML-строку как дочерний элемент в контейнер, нужно сначала создать DOM-элемент из этой HTML-строки. Это можно сделать, используя метод `createElement` и `insertAdjacentHTML`.

В вашем случае, вместо возвращения HTML-строки из функции `addCartItem`, попробуйте создать DOM-элемент с помощью `createElement`, заполнить его содержимым с помощью `insertAdjacentHTML` и затем вставить этот элемент в контейнер.

Примерно так:

```js
function addCartItem (title, price, img){ 
    let cartItem = document.createElement('div');
    cartItem.classList.add('popupCartItem');
    
    cartItem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
        <img src="${img}" alt="" class="popupCarItemtImg">
        <p class="popupCartItemName">${title}</p>
        <div class="popupCartPrice">
            <p class="popupCartPriceNum">${price}</p>
            <p class="popupCartPriceCredit">в кредит</p>
        </div>
        <svg class="popupCartItemDelete" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M2.21311 1.57107L16.3552 15.7132M2.21311 15.7132L16.3552 1.57107" stroke="#404040" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square" />
        </svg>
    `);

    return cartItem;
}

if(popularCars.length > 0) {
    let cartWrapper = document.querySelector('.popupCartWraper');
    
    for(let i = 0; i < popularCars.length; i++) {
        let carBtn = popularCars[i].querySelector('.popularSlideOstavitZayavku'),
            carTitle = popularCars[i].querySelector('.popularSlideName').textContent,
            carPrice = popularCars[i].querySelector('.popularSlideItemPriceText').textContent,
            carImg = popularCars[i].querySelector('.popularSlideImg').getAttribute('src');

        carBtn.onclick = () => {
            cartList.push({ 
                title: carTitle,
                price: carPrice, 
                img: carImg
            });

            cartWrapper.innerHTML = ''; // очищаем контейнер от предыдущих элементов

            cartList.forEach((cartItem) => {
                cartWrapper.appendChild(addCartItem(cartItem.title, cartItem.price, cartItem.img));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Таким образом HTML-элемент будет создан из строки `cartItem` с помощью `createElement` и добавлен в контейнер с помощью метода `appendChild`.